# Working with pointers: program that checks if strings are in lexicographical order

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strcmp

I am trying to make a program which checks if a list of Strings are in lexicographical order or not. If it is in order, the program should return 1, if not 0. To test the program I introduced the strings AA, BB and CC which obviously should be in order. However, the program return 0...

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int lex_sorted(const char* array[]){
  int k;

  for(k=0;*array+k+1!=NULL;k++){

    if(strcmp(*array+k,*array+k+1)<0){
      return 0;
    }

  }


  return 1;

}



int main(void){
  int result;
  const char* array[]={"AA","BB","CC",NULL};
  result= lex_sorted(array);
  printf("%d\n",result);
  return 0;
```

Comment: Your array termination check looks bogus. Look at it again.

Comment: Um if it is order checking you're doing, shouldn't all you need is to walk the list, checking *adjacent* pairs? Why the nested loop? (or did I miss something, it's way late-early here). Wouldn't a single loop, effectively the single opening pass of a bubblesort (without the exchanges), do what you want?

Comment: [Example of what I described above](http://ideone.com/C8ozq5).

Comment: I changed it to one loop, but it still gives me the return value 0 :(

Comment: @Mark  It is a very bad idea that you changed the code in your question, Now for readers answers can look irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `*arr+k` and `*(arr+k)`, `*arr+k+1` and `*(arr+k+1)` are two different expressions.
2. It should be `strcmp() > 0`, not `strcmp() < 0` as per requirement.
3. `i` should be initialised before each iteration (inner loop)

Tips:

- It would be easy for others to read if arrays are indexed. `arr[k]` instead of `*(arr+k)`
- Indetation can make a big difference while reading code.

Comment: I got that it should be >0. I understand that *arr+k and *(arr+k) are not the same, but I thought that I needed *arr+k because *arr returns the address which points to the first string, namely "AA". To access the others, I would add +k to the address.

Comment: @mark no  `*arr+k` only advances to kth element (char) in the string. because `*arr` is `char*`.

Comment: @mark the best way to understand pointers is by examining the assembly output of the program (if you know assembly). every thing will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

As the first string is less than the second string then the function returns 0 due to this statement

```
  if(strcmp(*array+k,*array+i+1)<0){
return 0;

  }
```

when `k` and `i` are equal to 0.

So what you do is what you get,

There is no sense to use two loops in the function. The function can be defined as it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int lex_sorted( const char* array[] )
{
    if ( *array )
    {
        while ( *++array && strcmp( array[-1], array[0] ) <= 0 );
    }

    return *array == NULL;
}   

int main(void) 
{
    const char * array[] = { "AA", "BB", "CC",  NULL };

    printf( "%d\n", lex_sorted( array ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1
```

because the array is ordered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed my programm to one loop, but it still gives the same output. Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @Mark I pointed out in my answer why the program returns 0. See my answer.

Comment: I dont get it. Shouldnt *array give me the adress of the string AA and *array+1 the adress of BB? In this case, why should strcmp(*array,*array+1)<0 ?

Comment: @Mark "AA' is less than "BB" so strcmp returns a negative value and in this case due to the if statement you return 0 from the function.

Comment: Well, shouldnt the problem be solved by just changing < to > ?

Comment: @Mark Yes, it can. But in any case the function has undefined behavior if the array has only one element because you are trying to access a non-existent element. And I think you mean ;*( array+k+1 ) instead of ;*array+k+1